# how to access the variables in 1st API function in the 2nd API function

Tags: javascript

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    $.getJSON(url_wind, function (data2) {
        //do stuff with 'data' and 'data2'
    });    
});
```

when I use the data of the first `getJSON()` in the 2nd `getJSON()` there is an error saying `undefined` help me please

Comment: Is the first URL returning valid json data ?

Comment: Accessing `data` and `data2` should work. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cdu7vjnk/) for a working example of it. Please create a [mre]

Comment: yes it returning valid data

Answer (score 0):

Use the promises rather this nesting. it's easy to debug.

Call it like this with async await.

```
(async function () {
    let data = await $.getJSON(url);
    let data2 = await $.getJSON(url_wind);
    console.log(data, data2);
})();
```

Comment: `$.getJSON` already returns a promise-like object. So you can instead you could do `const data = await $.getJSON(url);` and the same for `data2`. No need to wrap it in a new promise